# Google chart different label for x1-xn and for xn-xm

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I set the X label for the value between 1-5 and a different label for 5-9 and for 9-15 and etc.

I have a line chart. And I want to seet a label for the values beetwen 1-5(15,y) a different label for the value beetwe 5-9(5-9,y). The y can be evrything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: After the new details that you have add to the question I edit this post**

**EDIT: To make it a bit more clear in your situation**

If you want to use different labels for different values i suggest to use the addColum method from the DataTable object. ( https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#creatingpopulating ). It's not as straight as others methods to generate the datatable but is more flexible.

For instance let's supose that all the data of the points is placed in the next holder:

```
var data = [
    {x:"8:00",y:7.5},
    {x:"9:00",y:12.5},
    {x:"10:00",y:2.5} 
];
```

Then you can generate the chart, populate it and set the propper labels in the range of (1-5,5-9 and 9-15) like this:

```
dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Date');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Potatoes');
dataTable.addColumn({type:'string',role:'tooltip'});

var i, iMax = data.length;
for (i = 0; i < iMax; i++ ) {
    dataTable.addRow();
    dataTable.setValue(i, 0, data[i].x);
    dataTable.setValue(i, 1, data[i].y);
    if (data[i].y < 5 ) {
        dataTable.setValue(i, 2, "(1-5, "+data[i].y+")");
    } else if ( data[i].y < 9 ) {
        dataTable.setValue(i, 2, "(5-9, "+data[i].y+")");
    } else {
        dataTable.setValue(i, 2, "(9-15, "+data[i].y+")");
    }
}

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    somePlaceholder
);
chart.draw(
    dataTable,
    {
        title: "Title 1",
        hAxis: {title: "Title 2"},
        legend:'none',
    }
);
```

Comment: I want to use line chart :(

Comment: The problem is here that you use type string. But I need to use number (x,y) is a point and for this point I want to set a string label,text. Ex. for point=(5,2) text = "Value 5,2"

Comment: I don't know if i have undertand you well ... but at the end the label will be displayed as a string, right?. Then it can be constructed automatically as a string. For exemple "(1-5, "+x+")", or in the situation of (x,y) you can generate the label as "("+y+","+x+")" . Then put inside a loop that will red all the data and generate the addRow + setValues for all the data. Maybe i'm missing  something?

Comment: I have edited to make it more clear. Your data may have other holder but more and less this shows my point. Hope is what are you looking for :)

Comment: Please chec this picture. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/7s3j.png/ the picture you can see that I have numver for x and y the chart is populate from this. The chart aumaticly set the x label from the x valu but i want to change these label for a custom text how you can see on the picture

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.
While adding data to data table you can give the label name like this.

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['x', 'Cats', 'Blanket 1', 'Blanket 2'],
      ['A',   1,       1,           0.5],
      ['A',   2,       0.5,         1],
      ['A',   4,       1,           0.5],
      ['A',   8,       0.5,         1],
      ['B',   7,       1,           0.5],
      ['B',   7,       0.5,         1],
      ['B',   8,       1,           0.5],
      ['B',   4,       0.5,         1],
      ['C',   2,       1,           0.5],
      ['C',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
      ['C',   3,       1,           0.5],
      ['C',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
      ['C',   1,       1,           0.5],
      ['D',   1,       0.5,         1]
    ]);
```

Here is the working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/FAmVm/)